# PostgreSQL JSONB GIN Index multi condition

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm using PostgreSQL 13 and I have a table that has a JSONB column and GIN index.

My question is to find a better way for the following query. I have multiple IDs and sometimes I need to find them.

My Schema:

```
id  timestamp   data    
404599  2022-01-01 00:15:02.566 {"env": "worker", "id":1, "name": "foo", "lang": "en"}
404600  2022-01-01 00:15:02.685 {"env": "worker", "id":2, "name": "foo", "lang": "fr"}
404601  2022-01-01 00:15:02.808 {"env": "worker", "id":3, "name": "foo", "lang": "ru"}
404602  2022-01-01 00:15:03.023 {"env": "worker", "id":3, "name": "foo", "lang": "de"}
404603  2022-01-01 00:15:03.170 {"env": "worker", "id":4, "name": "foo", "lang": "tr"}
```

My Query:

```sql
select * from foo where data @>  '{"id": 1}' or data @> '{"id": 2}' or data @> '{"id": 3}';
```

I want to use the GIN index for the "`data`" column but I couldn't find any better way that looks like the "`in`" operator.

Comment: The example is nice, but please explain how to extrapolate it to reality.  A 5 row table probably doesn't need an index, and a query returning 60% of a table probably doesn't benefit from an index either.

Comment: The above table is not real. It's just an example. :)  My real table size is almost 2 TB and it has greater than 100 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the best way to query with a GIN index on the JSON column.

If all your queries look like that, using a b-tree index would be more efficient:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo ((data ->> 'id'));

SELECT * FROM foo WHERE data ->> 'id' IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems that I have to use that bad syntax.